# WiFi is connected but pages didn't open

Tags: 18.04, wireless, network-manager

I have Ubuntu 18.04 .. I connected WiFi and worked well until it stopped suddenly .. I just get words "waiting for www.google.com" as an example but couldn't see the site open.. something else facebook I got messages for notifications but the site itself didn't open .. 
I tried to edit the IP address in /etc/resolv.conf as 8.8.8.8 and restart the network but didn't work
I wrote the post in mobile so sorry of any mistake .. if something need to add in the post please tell me

Comment: are you able to ping 8.8.8.8 ? if yes, is there any change on your proxy(If one is used on your network)?

Comment: I pinged for 8.8.8.8 and working .. but how can I know if there is a change in proxy or not

Comment: i installed another browser and internet worked well

Comment: 1) Which browser were you using which had the problem? 2) Did you clear its cache and cookies with Ctrl-Shft-Del ? Please click [edit] to put your response in the question. Please do not respond with Add Comment.

Comment: the problem was with firefox and i installed google-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i installed google-chrome and internet worked well ---
the problem was with Firefox